# Prototype pattern vs creator delegate

Tags: design-patterns, prototype-pattern

So I read about [prototype pattern](http://ralphschindler.com/2012/03/09/php-constructor-best-practices-and-the-prototype-pattern) today and find that I actually came across this programming problem several times without realizing it myself.

My understanding from having read that article and wikipedia seems to be:

> Use prototype pattern to clone an existing object then change its
>   properties, instead of trying to create one from scratch when there is
>   no way to know beforehand its constructor or what it will be.

The way I usually solve this problem is to use a function delegate that returns the object:

```
// Pseudocode

// Library Routine
function GetTasks(CreateTaskDelegate callback) {
    var task = array();
    foreach(var rows as row) {
        tasks.push(callback($row));
    }
    return tasks;
}

// Library Interface / Abstract Class
class Task { }

// User Concrete Class
class MyCustomTask extends Task {}


// delegate "pattern"
GetTasks(function($row) {
    return new MyCustomTask($row);
});
```

How does this compare to the prototype pattern? It seems like the prototype pattern has a narrower applicable scope of usage, so what else is it good for?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `creator delegate` is actually `factory method` pattern I can say that differences between `prototype` and `factory method` are:

1. `Factory method` is the simplest of `create patterns`. `+` is simplicity. `-` one need to create child class on order to create different type of product.
2. `Prototype` uses another approach. Rather than inheritance it uses composition of objects. In that case there are some object that knows about how to create products(prototype) and it is assigned as parameter. `+` is agility. `-` is complexity.